# How to find your current location on Google Earth

Tags: google-earth

I have a Dell tablet with GPS that I'm trying to use Google Earth on. Is there a way to have it show your current location such that I can see myself move around on the map real time?

Comment: It has a GPS option still doesnt it? https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148095?hl=en-GB at the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 2):

To get your current location on google earth, try following these simple steps:

1. From google earth icons top of the earth view click on **view in google maps**, your web browser should open and take you to the google maps.
2. In the browser tab where google maps appears, look to the right bottom corner you should see a small dimmed circle with a dot inside **GPS locator** click that one and it will take you to your current location and place a dot on the map for marking your location.
3. click on the marked dot on the map, a small dialog box will appear with the name of your current location and coordinates, simply click on the coordinates and it will appear in the map search text box, copy it and paste it in google earth's search and hit search to be navigated to your current location in google earth.

Note: browser location access should be enabled.